# How to refer to my data when I have several columns with "x" and NAs?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame("Name"=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
                 "SM1"=c(NA, NA, "x", NA, "x", "x"), 
                 "SM2"=c("x", NA, NA, "x", "x", NA),
                 "SM3"=c("x", "x", "x", NA, NA, NA),
                 "Gender"=c("female", "male","male","male","female","female")
                 )
```

In this example I have several people using different supermarkets where the "x" marks which of them each person uses. Each of those people has other attributes like "Gender" etc.

I want to compare those attributes with stacked barplots using `ggplot2` for each of the supermarkets, like how many female and male customers each of the supermarkets has.

My problem is that I don't have one single column telling me which supermarket is used since each person can use each combination of supermarkets, and therefore I don't know how to refer to my data in order to plot it. How do I do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame("Name"=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
                 "SM1"=c(NA, NA, "x", NA, "x", "x"), 
                 "SM2"=c("x", NA, NA, "x", "x", NA),
                 "SM3"=c("x", "x", "x", NA, NA, NA),
                 "Gender"=c("female", "male","male","male","female","female"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = SM1:SM3, names_to = "sm", values_to = "gen") %>% 
  mutate(gen = case_when(gen == "x" ~ Gender,
                         TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  group_by(sm, gen) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  na.omit()


ggplot(df, aes(sm, count, fill = gen)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Which gives you:

[image]

Comment: Hm not quite, as this gives me a bar for each person. I need a stacked bar for each supermarket, showing f.e. 2 female+1 male customers for SM2 next to 1 female+2 male customers for SM3 next to each other.

Comment: OK then the Names column is not needed. See revised answer!

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm going for, thank you!

However, when I try to apply it to my data with  

`data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = SM1:SM3, names_to = "sm", values_to = "gen") %>% 
  mutate(gen = case_when(gen == "x" ~ Gender,
                        TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  group_by(sm, gen) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  na.omit()`  

I get the following error:
_Error: must be a `factor` object, not a character vector_  

What does that mean?

Comment: @Gotemn Have you included the  `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument in your dataframe?

Comment: Yes I did, but I just noticed it didn't work because I used `factor()` somewhere else in the code. Thank you for your help!